# restructuring multiple columns in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

Here is a sample of my data:

```html
dat<-read.table(text=" id bx1 Z1A Z1B Z1C QR1 bx2 Z2A Z2B Z2C QR2

1 1 1 2 3 C 18 2 2 1 E
2 11 2 3 3 B 14 3 3 3 A
",header=TRUE)
```

I want to get the following table:

```html
id bx Z QR Score
1 1 Z1A C 1
1 1 Z1B C 2
1 1 Z1C C 3
1 18 Z2A E 2
1 18 Z2B E 2
1 18 Z2C E 1
2 11 Z1A B 2
2 11 Z1B B 3
2 11 Z1C B 3
2 14 Z2A A 3
2 14 Z2B A 3
2 14 Z2C A 3
```

Assuming that I have more bxs and Zs and I have done this, but it does not work. I would like to do it with tidyverse or other pakages. I was unable to find out a solution.

```html
df1<-melt(dat, id.var= "id")
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the logic and why do you think melting is the best option?

Comment: You can use `pivot_longer`(with `contains`/`starts_with`) or `gather` thrice but I think that's inefficient. What happens to bx2 and bx3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, we can use a `left_join` after separately doing the `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
dat %>% 
   select(id, starts_with('Z')) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Z'), values_to = 'Score', 
         names_to = 'Z') %>%
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(group =  as.character(as.integer(factor(str_remove(Z, "[A-Z]$"))))) %>% 
   left_join(dat %>% 
                  select(id, matches('^[^Z]')) %>% 
                  pivot_longer(cols = -id, names_to = c(".value", "group"),
            names_pattern = "^([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)")) %>%
   select(-group)
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   id [2]
#      id Z     Score    bx QR   
#   <int> <chr> <int> <int> <fct>
# 1     1 Z1A       1     1 C    
# 2     1 Z1B       2     1 C    
# 3     1 Z1C       3     1 C    
# 4     1 Z2A       2    18 E    
# 5     1 Z2B       2    18 E    
# 6     1 Z2C       1    18 E    
# 7     2 Z1A       2    11 B    
# 8     2 Z1B       3    11 B    
# 9     2 Z1C       3    11 B    
#10     2 Z2A       3    14 A    
#11     2 Z2B       3    14 A    
#12     2 Z2C       3    14 A
```

---

Or another option is to do a single `pivot_longer` and then `fill` the selected columns

```
dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -id, names_to = c(".value", "group"),
         names_pattern = "^([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+[A-Z]?)") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(bx, QR) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Z)) %>% 
  rename_at(vars(Z, group), ~ c('Score', 'Z')) %>%
  mutate(Z = str_c('Z', Z))
# A tibble: 12 x 5
#      id Z        bx Score QR   
#   <int> <chr> <int> <int> <fct>
# 1     1 Z1A       1     1 C    
# 2     1 Z1B       1     2 C    
# 3     1 Z1C       1     3 C    
# 4     1 Z2A      18     2 E    
# 5     1 Z2B      18     2 E    
# 6     1 Z2C      18     1 E    
# 7     2 Z1A      11     2 B    
# 8     2 Z1B      11     3 B    
# 9     2 Z1C      11     3 B    
#10     2 Z2A      14     3 A    
#11     2 Z2B      14     3 A    
#12     2 Z2C      14     3 A
```